# Retry logic using lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to build a retry logic and interested in passing the code as a parameter. I already searched a number of threads but somehow missing to connect the dots here.

Sample B works perfectly fine, where as sample A starts yelling 'Type argument cannot be inferred from the usage. I'm trying this for the first time to please bear with me here.

Retry code has been mentioned below.

Reason for trying Sample A is because I wish to combine Foo and Bar , so that it can make a block of code being sent to retry rather than a single call to function. What is that I'm missing here ?

```
    //SAMPLE A
    Retry.Do(() => {
        Foo();
        Bar(); 
        }, 120, 3);
    //SAMPLE B
    Retry.Do(() => Foo(), 120, 3);

    public static void Do<T>(
    Func<T> action,
    int RetryInterval,
    int RetryCount)
{

    Exception LastException = null;
    for (int retry = 0; retry < RetryCount; retry++)
    {
        try
        {
            Actions.FabricActions.Sleep(RetryInterval, "");
            action();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Exception(ex, "Exception encountered on retry attempt {0}", RetryCount);
            LastException = ex;
        }
    }

    if (LastException != null)
        throw LastException;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the signature to this:

```
public static void Do(
    Action action,
    int RetryInterval,
    int RetryCount)
{
}
```

`Func<T>` means you expect a return type of `T`. You are not returning anything in your methods, so it fails to compile. If you *do* want to return something, keep the function definition as it is, but make sure you return within your call, like this:

```
Retry.Do(() => {
        Foo();
        return Bar(); 
        }, 120, 3);

//This is only valid because it's short hand for 'return Foo();', since you don't have { }
Retry.Do(() => Foo(), 120, 3);
// Or
Retry.Do(() => { return Foo() }, 120, 3);
// Or with method groups (only valid for sample B)
Retry.Do(Foo, 120, 3);
```

Be aware that if you *are* returning a value, `Do` is not - so you're throwing away the return value. Whether or not this is okay is up to you. But you could change `Do` to return `T`, and do this: `return action();` instead of just `action();`